# QTextEdit. Проблема с setEnabled

Tags: qt

Нажимая два раза на TextEdit(кастомный класс, наследующий QTextEdit) устанавливаю флаг Enabled = true, а если нажать все этого TextEdit-а, то флаг(или аттрибут, как такое называется?) Enabled = false. Все работает, но если выделить текст и потом нажать вне TextEdit-a то `alpha` текста или что-то не меняется. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]